# How can I fix this error when I'm counting the number of dots in a cell of Pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm just trying to count the number of times '.' appears in a cell of a Pandas data frame.
So I tried:

```
df['n dots'] = df['field'].count('.')
```

But I got the error:

```
KeyError: 'Requested level (.) does not match index name (None)'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try ```str.count()```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Your first reflex should be to check [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html), which should make it rather clear what the issue is.

Comment: Do you want to count `.` in all rows of a column or in a specific cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html), you need to add a backslash or it will be interpreted as a regular expression

```
df['n dots'] = df['field'].str.count('\.')
```